# Why can the name of a `MathOperator` have a number?

Tags: macros, math-operators, catcodes

This does not compile, which is what I'd expect:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newcommand{\G2}{G_2}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\G2}{G_2}
\begin{document}
\(\G2\)
\end{document}
```

produces

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.2 \newcommand{\G2}{G_2}
                             
?
```

This does compile, which is not what I'd expect:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%\newcommand{\G2}{G_2}
\DeclareMathOperator{\G2}{G_2}
\begin{document}
\(\G2\)
\end{document}
```

Why does it compile?

Comment: Because it defines `\G` robust as `\protect \G2 ` (note the space after the 2). (See the result of `\show\G`.) IMHO this is not a designed feature, but the result of ignoring, that the argument of `\DeclareMathOperator` has to be a valid command sequence (without testing it). For example `\DeclareMathOperator{\G.!}{G_2}` would also work, but should not be used. And `\newcommand*{\G}{…}` after one of these would not work. BTW: You can get similar results using `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\DeclareMathOperator`.

Comment: @cabohah, [re](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/692785/why-can-the-name-of-a-mathoperator-have-a-number#comment1719103_692785), thanks!  But the invocation seems to treat `\G2`, not `\G`, as the command, despite the catcode.  That is, it typesets as if I'd written `\(\operatorname{G_2}\)`, not `\(\operatorname{G_2}2\)`.

Comment: @cabohah, [re](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/692785/why-can-the-name-of-a-mathoperator-have-a-number#comment1719103_692785), ah, wait, I might see your point better now.  I'm not really familiar with robust commands and `\protect`, so pardon my misunderstanding.  Are you saying that it is like writing `\def\G2{\operatorname{G_2}}`, where the `2` is not part of the command name, but part of the required syntax of its invocation?  If so, and if you post that as an answer, then I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Yes. You can easy test it, using `\G  something`, which would result in `Use of \G doesn't match its definition.` because a `s` is following to `\G` instead of a `2`. And because of this, it would, i.e., not work so *additionally* define a `\DeclareMathOperator{\G3}{G_3}` and use both of them. `\G3` definition would just overwrite the `\G2` definition, because not `\G2` and `\G3` are defined but only `\G`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `amsopn.sty` we see

```
\newcommand{\DeclareMathOperator}{%
  \@ifstar{\@declmathop m}{\@declmathop o}}
```

Note that in this context, `@` is a letter. In your case there is no `*` following, so TeX will transform

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\G2}{G_2}
```

into

```
\@declmathop o{\G2}{G_2}
```

Now we look for the definition of `\@declmathop`:

```
\long\def\@declmathop#1#2#3{%
  \@ifdefinable{#2}{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand{#2}{\qopname\newmcodes@#1{#3}}}}
```

so we obtain

```
\@ifdefinable{\G2}{\DeclareRobustCommand{\G2}{\qopname\newmcodes@o{G_2}}}
```

Well, it seems that one of the culprits is `\@ifdefinable`. Indeed

```
% latex.ltx, line 1287:
\long\def\@ifdefinable #1#2{%
      \edef\reserved@a{\expandafter\@gobble\string #1}%
     \@ifundefined\reserved@a
         {\edef\reserved@b{\expandafter\@carcube \reserved@a xxx\@nil}%
          \ifx \reserved@b\@qend \@notdefinable\else
            \ifx \reserved@a\@qrelax \@notdefinable\else
              #2%
            \fi
          \fi}%
         \@notdefinable}
```

In your case we have `\G2` as `#1` and the other braced group is `#2`:

```
\edef\reserved@a{\expandafter\@gobble\string\G2}
```

which defines `\reserved@a` to expand to `G2`, which likely makes `\@ifundefined\reserved@a` to return true. Thus we get

```
\edef\reserved@b{\expandafter\@carcube \reserved@a xxx\@nil}
\ifx \reserved@b\@qend
  \@notdefinable
\else
  \ifx \reserved@a\@qrelax
    \@notdefinable
  \else
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\G2}{\qopname\newmcodes@o{G_2}}
  \fi
\fi
```

(reformatted, but there is actually no endline in the token list). Now the first test returns false as well as the second test, so you get

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\G2}{\qopname\newmcodes@o{G_2}}
```

Second culprit here, because we see that

```
% latex.ltx, line 1376:
\def\DeclareRobustCommand{\@star@or@long\declare@robustcommand}
% latex.ltx, line 1226:
\def\@star@or@long#1{%
  \@ifstar
   {\let\l@ngrel@x\relax#1}%
   {\let\l@ngrel@x\long#1}}
% latex.ltx, line 1377:
\def\declare@robustcommand#1{%
   \ifx#1\@undefined\else\ifx#1\relax\else
      \@latex@info{Redefining \string#1}%
   \fi\fi
   \edef\reserved@a{\string#1}%
   \def\reserved@b{#1}%
   \edef\reserved@b{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\reserved@b}%
   \edef#1{%
      \ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b
         \noexpand\x@protect
         \noexpand#1%
      \fi
      \noexpand\protect
      \expandafter\noexpand\csname
         \expandafter\@gobble\string#1 \endcsname
   }%
   \let\@ifdefinable\@rc@ifdefinable
   \expandafter\new@command\csname
      \expandafter\@gobble\string#1 \endcsname
}
```

The `\@star@or@long` part is irrelevant here and we get

```
\declare@robustcommand{\G2}{\qopname\newmcodes@o{G_2}}
```

and this is transformed into

```
\ifx\G2\@undefined
\else
  \ifx\G2\relax
  \else
    \@latex@info{Redefining \string\G2}%
  \fi
\fi
```

(and more tokens to follow). The first conditional compares `\G` with `2` and they differ, so `\@undefined` is skipped and we get nothing from this part. Next we have the actual definition and, basically, LaTeX eventually does

```
\edef\G2{\noexpand\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname G2 \endcsname}
\expandafter\def\csname G2 \endcsname{\qopname\newmcodes@o{G_2}}
```

As you see, the first `\edef` is legal, as far as TeX is concerned. Indeed, if you do `\show\G` in your file, you get

```
> \G=macro:
2->\protect \G2  .
```

which means that `\G` ***must*** be followed by an explicit token `2` and the combination is transformed into `\protect\G2•` (the bullet denotes a space in the command name).

You'd get no error also if you further do

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\G3}{G_3}
```

but an error will be raised if you try to call `\G2`, because `\G` has been redefined to want `3` after it.

Possibly `\@ifdefinable` should check that its argument consists of a single token. But it doesn't.

Anyway, a *main* rule of TeX is that macro names consist of letters only or a single nonletter.

Comment: Thank you! @cabohah gave a terser explanation in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/692785/why-can-the-name-of-a-mathoperator-have-a-number#comment1719103_692785), whose only fault was that I wasn't familiar enough with the innards to follow their point.  Your lengthier explanation helps me see exactly what's going on, and I appreciate the details. \\ P.S. Do you ever sleep? Your ability to come up with careful, detailed answers seemingly at any time and at lightning speed is awe-inspiring.